# Python: Remove just the square bracket and leave everything as it is

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way, i can only remove just the square bracket and leave everything as it is.

```
y = (j['id'], (j['name'].split("_wiv0293_", 1)), j['policy'], j['status'])
print (y)
```

current output:-

> ('2', ['job01', '11-30-2019_04.05.02'], 'SCV', 'Completed')
>
> ('3', ['job02', '11-30-2019_20.15.02'], 'DLY', 'Completed')

The required output should be:-

> ('2', 'job01', '11-30-2019_04.05.02', 'SCV', 'Completed')
>
> ('3', 'job02', '11-30-2019_20.15.02', 'DLY', 'Completed')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample to achieve your requirements.

```
y = ('2', ['job01', '11-30-2019_04.05.02'], 'SCV', 'Completed')


def convert_function(y):
    a = []

    for i in y:
       if type(i) is list:
           for item in i:
               a.append(item)
       else:
           a.append(i)

    return tuple(a)

final_y = convert_function(y)
print(final_y)
```

Comment: it is not giving appropriate output,missing single quotes before and after the comma.

('2', 'job01', '11-30-2019_04.05.02, SCV', 'Completed')

('3', 'job02', '11-30-2019_20.15.02, DLY', 'Completed')

Comment: Can anyone please help, i am still not able to get required output.